# Arctoolboxes suddenly unresponsive

Tags: arcgis-10.1, error, arctoolbox

My Arcgis Desktop 10.1 was working fine until, suddenly, I became unable to use the Arctoolbox tools :

- when I try to open them from the arctoolbox window they just do not answer,
- when I try to open them from the search tool I get a warning/error message:

> Warning
>
> Adding this item is not supported or the application that opens it is not found.

I've done researches on internet, but although some problems deal with arctoolbox dysfunctionalities, I found none that are quite like mine.

Anybody has a suggestion or solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick search on ArcGIS and that error returned several possibilities on the first page that at least partially match your description. The first question I would ask is what if anything changed 'suddenly' - system updates? Application of a service pack? Installed a new program? Nothing at all? Some of the suggested fixes that worked for some people include:

1) Check the location/path of the python folder. Is it still there, not overly long, and does not contain spaces or special characters?

2) Try running a tool after logging in to a different user account, possibly creating a new one to test. If the tool runs, your user profile data may have been corrupted; deleting it and having Arc recreate it may fix the problem. If it still won't run the problem may be deeper.

3) Check the Windows System Environment variables to see if the python path is still listed and pointing where it should.

4) It's possible Windows Registry corruption has occurred and some of those same path issues are coming from there. You could attempt to track them through the registry editor, but reinstalling Arc may prove faster and more reliable.

Comment: +1, it was close to that, for some reason few files went hidden and apparently ArcGIS could not access them, I've just changed their status to unhidden and it's all now working fine. Thanks anyway for your answer.

Comment: Where did they go hidden? I'm having this same problem and would love more info on your fix.

Comment: @user54396 'Hidden' is a file attribute - see http://www.2brightsparks.com/resources/articles/understanding-file-attributes.html for more info. There are several ways to reset the hidden flag - from a command prompt, or ensuring Explorer is displaying hidden files (which are usually gray rather than black text for the name) and/or their attributes, right-click > properties them, and uncheck the box.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue with ArcGIS Desktop 10.4 and [Solution 2)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/91348/115) worked for me.

> "2) Try running a tool after logging in to a different user account,
>   possibly creating a new one to test. If the tool runs, your user
>   profile data may have been corrupted; deleting it and having Arc
>   recreate it may fix the problem. If it still won't run the problem may
>   be deeper"

The "toolbox folder" in my account was corrupted.
For file location refer to [Resetting your GIS app' profile](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/78692)

From the Newly created computer admin account, i found and I copied the whole folder and replaced the corrupted one in my usual computer admin account and it worked perfectly.